# Difference between Cisco ASA logs and PIX

Tags: cisco

I wanted to know the major difference between Cisco ASA and Pix logs . If there are any good links that will be great.

Answer (score 1):

The Cisco syslog format and messages have remained consistent across their security devices.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa72/system/message/syslog.html

http://www.cisco.com/univercd/cc/td/doc/product/iaabu/pix/pix_v53/syslog/pixemsgs.htm

Answer (score 1):

The major difference will be that on PIX, message will begin with %PIX and on ASA with %ASA
You may look at http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/system/message/logsevp.html
Where you will see all message of PIX and ASA. As you will see some message only exist on PIX and some only on ASA.